# Spyder: ImportError no module named 'strict'

Tags: python, spyder

I am using Anaconda 2.7 and installed the Augustus (pmml) package in Spyder, but cannot import the strict.py module.

I used !pip in Spyder to install Augustus and added the path to the site-packages folder in Spyder.

I can't figure out what is wrong and feel like a small idiosyncrasy is missing.

Comment: Please provide your import code.

Comment: from augustus.strict import *

I have set the path to the site-packages folder in Anaconda.